# Finding relation between residue at $1$ and the Taylor coefficients at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega=\{z:|z|<2\}$ and f be a holomorphic function on $\Omega$ which is
holomorphic at every point of  $\Omega$ except $z = 1$ and at $z = 1$ it has a
simple pole. Suppose that $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n, \text{  for  }|z|<2 .$$

Prove that $\text{lim}_{n\rightarrow \infty}\text{ }
a_n = −c$, where $c$ is the residue of $f$ at $z = 1$

If we look at $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$, we can see the result. I tried to find the relation between coefficients but I could not work it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The residue at 1 is : $$\lim_{z\to 1} \; (z-1)\sum_{n=0} a_n z^n= -\lim_{z\to 1} \; \sum_{n=1} (a_{n}-a_{n-1}) z^n = -\sum_{n=1} \lim_{z\to 1} \; (a_n-a_{n-1}) z^n = -\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$

You'd just have to justify the exchange of summation and the limit.